# htaccess rewrite directory/file references to new url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite all files located below a URL such as:

http://www.example.com/one/

to a new URL:

http://www.newhome.com/new/

So, the desired functionality is to have http://www.example.com/asdf and http://www.example.com/ both remain on www.example.com, but http://www.example.com/one/test/index.php would pull content from:

http://www.newhome.com/new/test/index.php

I can't quite get the correct rewrite rule to do this. Any ideas?

EDIT: The rewrite rule needs to have requests from http://www.example.com/one/* retain the URL in the browser, but pull content from http://www.newhome.com/new/test/* (the rewritten locations will include forms and form submissions).

Of note, the .htaccess file will go in the equivalent of the '/one' directory (because of server access restrictions)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put this rule as your first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^one/.*$ /new/test/index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava. this is close. But more specifically, I want to retain the 'example.com' url.  I'll update my question.

Comment: You need to understand that if rewrite `example.com => newhome.com` happens then URL will surely change in the browser unless you enable `mod_proxy` in your Apache config.

Comment: Let me know if you have `mod_proxy` enabled?